# Crypto: encrypt or decrypt string

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, cryptojs

I try crypt and decrypt a string in cookieStorage, but when I execute my code I have message like this method is obsolete and it's not work

My code :

```
    const crypto = requite('crypto');        

    app.get("/crypto", (req, res) => {
       var word = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVlMzBiZjE0YmQ4OTNmMmE5Y2Q1Y2I5MSIsInJvbGVzIjoiVVNFUl9ST0xFIiwiZW1haWwiOiJjYW1lcmF0ZXN0ODExQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImlhdCI6MTU4MDMzNjc1MCwiZXhwIjoxNTgwMzk2NzUwfQ.2bbqkoX7qhyX7lyLjBtlGPe08-oHGjO83nNIPxAzHv8";
      var algorithm = "aes-256-ct";
      var password = "3zTvzr3p67VC61jmV54rIYu1545x4TlY";
      var hw = encrypt(word, algorithm, password);
      console.log("encrypt: ", hw);
      console.log("decrypt: ", decrypt(hw, algorithm, password));
    });

    function encrypt(text, algorithm, password) {
      var cipher = crypto.createCipher(algorithm, password);
      var crypted = cipher.update(text, "utf8", "hex");
      crypted += cipher.final("hex");
      return crypted;
    }

    function decrypt(text, algorithm, password) {
      var decipher = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm, password);
      var dec = decipher.update(text, "hex", "utf8");
      dec += decipher.final("utf8");
      return dec;
    }
```

Comment: Hi. A method is obsolete but ... which one ?

Comment: try having a look at the API : https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html

Comment: this methods: createCipher and createDecipher

Comment: error messages or warnings are there to be read, and usually give very specific information about how to potentially fix the issue.

Comment: I put two console.log and it's not display, I have one warning about this (createCipher and createDecipher) that it's not deprecated to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's works with this :

```
exports.encrypt = (text, ENCRYPTION_KEY, IV_LENGTH) => {
    let iv = crypto.randomBytes(IV_LENGTH);
    let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(
      "aes-256-cbc",
      Buffer.from(ENCRYPTION_KEY),
      iv
    );
    let encrypted = cipher.update(text);
    encrypted = Buffer.concat([encrypted, cipher.final()]);
    return iv.toString("hex") + ":" + encrypted.toString("hex");
  }

  exports.decrypt = (text, ENCRYPTION_KEY, IV_LENGTH) => {
    let textParts = text.split(":");
    let iv = Buffer.from(textParts.shift(), "hex");
    let encryptedText = Buffer.from(textParts.join(":"), "hex");
    let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(
      "aes-256-cbc",
      Buffer.from(ENCRYPTION_KEY),
      iv
    );
    let decrypted = decipher.update(encryptedText);
    decrypted = Buffer.concat([decrypted, decipher.final()]);
    return decrypted.toString();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`createCipher` is deprecated, use  `crypto.createCipheriv()` instead.

`createDecipher` is deprecated, use `crypto.createDecipheriv()` instead.

Source: https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipher_algorithm_password_options

Comment: I used (crypto.createCipheriv() and crypto.createDecipheriv()) but console.log display nothing

Answer (score 1):

you can use npm crypto-js to encrypt and decrypt the string in

Comment: Active development of crypto-js has now been discontinued. They recommend using the  Web Crypto API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API).

That said, crypto-js is still widely used with npmjs.com reporting over 6 million weekly downloads at time of writing. crypto-js is very easy to use, though just be aware that the Web Crypto API is probably the better option to choose.